# Can a high frequency hardware input be accurately read under a windows or windows CE environment?

Tags: io, driver, hardware

This question straddles the blurry line between software and hardware so I hope the community feels it belongs on stackoverflow otherwise I would appreciate some advice as to where to move it.

My team is currently in the process of developing a robotic controller and although most of our I/O requirements are pretty tame we have one specific input that occasionally triggers at a 2 microsecond interval (Either a digital rise or fall). We need to be able to accurately timestamp that input and record it. We do not need to act on it in any sort of immediate way.  We feel as if we should be able to take advantage of a high speed USB or PCI-E bus in order to facilitate this kind of high speed input but we lack expertise in this area and do not know what a solution to this problem would look like or if it even can be achieved without expensive/very invovled proprietary solutions. In addition there is a desire in our group to move away from Windows CE to a Windows Embedded (probably XP) x86 based platform however if this is something that could only be achieved on a CE system that would be important to know.

In summary:
Is there a way to read and timestamp accurately a 2 microsecond (500 KHz) input under a windows or windows CE environment?

Bonus points for implementation ideas/visions/methods!

Thank you!

Comment: at 2 mil and 500k you are going to have trouble not filtering it as noise. I assume it can be done but you are going to probably need to make a special piece of hardware that would just listen for that signal and then not in real time log it. That is to say your custom piece of hardware is going to listen for the signal, log it and then transfer it to the controlling software solution.

Comment: There's a good chance that if your line is banging away at this rate (or potentially can), that you'll still be processing the previous interrupt when the next turns up.   You won't get accurate time-stamping and there's every change that your system will get DOSed.  I think we're looking at specialist hardware  - probably consisting of a FPGA that captures the edges and timestamps them.

Comment: On almost any platofrm, 2usec leaves very little time for the CPU to process the interrupt and timestamp it.  You really should be timestamping it in hardware and stuffing it into a FIFO for the CPU to process in more manageable chunks.

Comment: Currently we have a micro controller that can catch this signal with hardware interrupts. Basically what everyone is thinking that with computer running windows or windows CE can't trigger on a hardware signal fast enough to catch this kind of signal. Instead some sort of buffer is going to necessary.

Comment: I'm with the hardware folks on this one. One of the biggest issues of accurately timestamping fast signals is that windows / windows CE is NOT a real time operating system. You have no guarentee that you would be able to process the signal within the given requirement. Go with hardware!

Comment: I've been looking into this a little bit. Would a kernel level driver provide the kind of low level access to timers, interrupts, buses, and other hardware signals combined with a custom PCI-E card perhaps meet my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt try to do it directly in windows?  What GPIO do you have anyway on your windows machine?   For around or under $20 there are a long list of solutions that are either serial or usb based (of the shelf microcontroller boards) which you could program to have their only job to be to watch that I/O and time stamp it and then casually send this data over usb or serial (or other) to the host.

I am thinking along the lines of the msp430 launchpad, or stellaris lauchpad, or stm32f0 discovery or stm32f4 discovery, the family of arduinos, mbed, leaf labs maple mini, and on and on.

To do it properly under windows you would need to add some hardware anyway...

Comment: note I wouldnt try it directly with linux on the same hardware either, I would still add a cheap peripheral to do the job. (it is not JUST a windows problem)

Comment: This is probably a simple question worthy of just a Yes or No answer but, "Would it be possible to sync the time on one of those peripherals to that of the main computer?"

Comment: yes, and no, depends on the accuracy.  could have a transmission over whatever interface happen periodically with whatever the time of the peripheral is, and you can try to sync that with the host.  But just like the problem with using I/O and accurate timing you have the same problem with going through who knows how many drivers with however many applications running causing latency in this information making it to whatever software is looking for it.